# MapBox Issue with build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, mapbox

I have a problem with `build.gradle`. Everytime I add the code from `Mapstore` I get an **Error**.
My build gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and yeah I pasted an `MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN`

and this is how I implemented the implementation:

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2'){
        exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
    }
```

Comment: "i get an Error" , post it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share exactly what your error is displaying as? Your code looks like it is matching the requirements so far listed here: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/